# xpath query - select nested text

Tags: xpath

I am trying to retrieve the number in the data-appid "284950097". I can get to section app '//div[@class="section app"]'.
However, I am not sure how to get to data-appid. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
<div class="section app" data-appid="284950097" data-updateid="5999903">
<div class="slide-wrap">
 <a href="/business/memengo-wallet" class="block-link">
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the attribute, use this syntax:

```
"//div[@class="section app"]/@data-appid"
```